# how do i use an adress stored in a variable to access a memory location

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, emu8086

I'm handling interrupts in 8086 assembly, and I need to print the value at an address [BX+SI+3fh], the 3fh is stored in some variable.

```
mov ax, word ptr [BX+SI+var]
;... print ax ...
```

The problem is that in [BX+SI+var], address of var is used and not the value.
So it translates into [BX+SI+0002h]
How do I get it to use var as a value?

Comment: Add it to one of the registers first. E.g. `add si, [var]; mov ax, [bx+si]` (assuming your variable is 16 bit).

Comment: it might overflow, for example, if var is 00FFh and SI is FFEFh

Comment: So what ... it would overflow anyway. It will wrap around, in 16 bit you have 64k segments so you can't address outside.

Comment: If you want to handle overflow differently than by wrapping around a single 64 KiB segment, you should add all components into one address register (`bx` or `si` or `di` or perhaps `bp`) and add `jc` conditional branches after each `add` instruction. At the targets of those branches, do something to handle the overflow, eg advance the used segment register by 1000h (equivalent to addressing the next 64 KiB).

Comment: Overflow is only a concern if the data structure being accessed/addressed is setup to cross a boundary.  When data is set up sensibly for the environment, overflow in addressing is not an issue.

Comment: The cpu wraps the address in `[bx+si+offset]` the same way a separate `add` does so that does not change overflow behavior. If you need a different handling that is a different question than what you asked.

Comment: x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing, and at most 2 registers per addressing mode, so you need an`add` of the value from memory.  Note that unsigned wrap-around is normal and fine if any of the numbers are signed-negative.  If you want to use huge far pointers where a single array can be larger than 64K, then yeah you'd want to check for signed or unsigned overflow (depending on how you intend your numbers to be treated) and as ecm says update the segment base.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to adjust this code depending on what segment your variable `var` is stored in, but here's a generic example:

```
;assumes SI is already loaded with the desired value.
;assumes segment where var is stored is already loaded into DS

mov al, byte ptr [ds:var]  ;in this example, loads 3Fh into AL
xor ah,ah                  ;set AH to zero, so that AX = 003F
add bx,ax                  ;BX = BX + 3Fh
mov ax, word ptr [bx+si]   ;load from [BX + SI + value of var]
```